# Accessing SQL Server using Integrated Security from an ASMX run in authenticated user context

Tags: sql, asmx, windows-authentication

I have a Webservice running in Windows Authentication mode.

I have an application to text the asmx connections:

```
BasicHttpBinding basicHttpBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();
BasicHttpBinding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly;
basicHttpBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Windows;

EndpointAddress endpoint = new EndpointAddress("http://xyzts/Service.asmx");
WS_SPIL.ServiceSoapClient client = new WS_SPIL.ServiceSoapClient(basicHttpBinding, endpoint);

client.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = Sytem.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;
client.ChannelFactory.Credentials.Windows.ClientCredential = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
```

I execute the folloing code (on the ASMX): User.Identity.Name which returns my windows AD login.

So far so good.

Now i want to connect to the database with the login in user. 
But i get the error message that the current user (the IIS user) doesn't have the privilige to connect to the sql server.

```
try
{
    SqlConnectionStringBuilder csb = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
    csb.DataSource = "sqlservername";
    csb.InitialCatalog = "DBName";
    csb.IntegratedSecurity = true;

    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
    conn.ConnectionString = csb.ToString();
    conn.Open();
    conn.Close();

    return "ok";
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    return ex.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a case of the "[double-hop problem](http://www.bing.com/search?q=double-hop%20problem&qs=n&form=QBRE&pq=double-hop%20problem&sc=1-18&sp=-1&sk=)". Basically, you can't get SQL Server to use the impersonated credentials unless you have Kerberos implemented.

Comment: Hi John,Thaks for your answer. I'm using the Kerberos as authentication.